# SQL count field that matches criteria from another field

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a field of account numbers that tie into account ID's.
how would I get a total count of all the ID's paid with account numbers(and add in the new column into my temp table.

```
for the sake of sanity
ID = ID
ACCOUNT NUMBER = ACCT
COUNT = COUNT (NEW COLUMN) 

ID |ACCOUNT NUMBER (GIVEN)   
1  |123           
1  |124           
2  |125           
3  |126           
3  |127           
3  |128           
3  |129           
4  |130           
5  |131           
5  |132           
5  |133           
5  |134           
5  |135           
5  |136           
5  |137           


ID |ACCOUNT NUMBER|COUNT  
1  |123           |2     
1  |124           |2     
2  |125           |1     
3  |126           |3     
3  |127           |3     
3  |128           |3     
3  |129           |3     
4  |130           |1     
5  |131           |7     
5  |132           |7     
5  |133           |7     
5  |134           |7     
5  |135           |7     
5  |136           |7     
5  |137           |7
```

Comment: The temp table is #TEMP if a new one must be created create to #TEMP2, also assume that there is 100,000+ accts.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here? Could you try to elaborate some?

Comment: I was doing an over partition, and if the count was > 1 pull all the accounts that meat that criteria. that being the case, the first account is excluded because it goes 1,123,1 1,124,2 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a windowing function.

```
COUNT([Account Number]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID])
```

**EDIT:**

This should help exclude anything with a count of one.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ID, ACCT, COUNT(ACCT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS [Count]
  FROM my_table) x
WHERE x.[Count] > 1
```

Comment: It is what I used before, the problem was the count would start at 1 go to 2 to 3 to 4, start over at 1 etc.... I need to exclude all accounts that have only 1 instance of the unique ID

Comment: @waterguard if you include in the question what you've tried it would be helpful. Maybe there's just a syntax mistake the causing the issue. I'd recommend this as the answer too (I would have posted this as an answer if it wasn't already there).

Comment: Actually, I was doing an over partition, just using row_number instead of count. count worked for me. thanks @norlando

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `group by`

```
select T1.ID, T1.ACCT, T2.Total
from #Temp T1 join
  (select ID, COUNT(*) Total
   from #Temp
   group by ID
   having count(*) > 1) T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```